# No method found annotated with @Named#value on upper class

Tags: java, mapstruct

i'm using mapstruct with bellow dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Then i have an interface that contain basic `@Named` method:

```java
public interface CommonConverter {
    @Named("formatDateString")
    default String formatDateString(Date date){
        if(date == null){
            return null;
        }
        return DateUtils.formatDateString(date);
    }
    @Named("formatStringDate")
    default Date formatStringDate(String dateStr){
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(dateStr)){
            return null;
        }
        return DateUtils.formatStringDate(dateStr);
    }

    @Named("convertTimestampToString")
    default String convertTimestampToString(Long date) {
        if (date == null || date.equals(0L)){
            return StringUtils.EMPTY;
        }
        return DateUtils.convertTimeToDateStr(date, 0);
    }
}
```

Now i have another mapstruct converter which extend `CommonConverter`

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface EmployeeEventConverter extends CommonConverter{
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "claimDate", target = "claimDate", qualifiedByName = "formatDateString"),
            @Mapping(source = "eventStartDate", target = "eventStartDate", qualifiedByName = "formatDateString"),
            //@Mapping(source = "target", target = "targetAsString", qualifiedByName = "formatTargetString"),
            @Mapping(source = "target", target = "targets", qualifiedByName = "convertTarget")
    })
    EmployeeEventClaimDTO toClaimDTO(EmployeeEventClaimDO entity);
    List<EmployeeEventClaimDTO> toClaimDTOs(List<EmployeeEventClaimDO> entities);
}
```

This class works ok until i upgrade to `1.4.1.Final` , i got this exception when compile the project:

```sh
Qualifier error. No method found annotated with @Named#value: [ formatDateString ].
```

To overcome this, i need to copy all `@Named` to class `EmployeeEventConverter` (and many other similar classes) which increase LOC and duplicated code. 
Anybody know why it happen and how to solve it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Alternative to extends

instead of `extends` you can try the `uses` property of the `Mapper` annotation.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = CommonConverter.class )
public interface EmployeeEventConverter
```

## Reporting issue at MapStruct

This however does feel like an issue with Mapstruct.
Can you check if this problem also exists when using the `1.4.2.Final` version or the `1.5.0.RC1` version? If so then please create an issue at https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues.

Comment: thanks, your solution works fine. i also submitted issue for mapstruct team